Flutter GoRouter Shows Black Screen After Sign-In Due to Provider Refresh
I'm working on a Flutter app where I'm using GoRouter for navigation and Riverpod for state management. After a user signs in, I want to redirect them to the home screen. However, I'm encountering a black screen issue after sign-in, which I suspect is due to multiple refreshes caused by the providers.
Details:
I'm using Riverpod to manage authentication state with firebaseAuthRepositoryProvider.
I have GoRouter set up with routes for sign-in, account setup, business setup, and the home screen.
The redirect function in GoRouter uses the state from firebaseAuthRepositoryProvider, userInfoProvider, and businessProvider to determine the navigation path.
GoRouter Configuration :
` @riverpod
GoRouter goRouter(GoRouterRef ref) {
final authRepository = ref.watch(firebaseAuthRepositoryProvider);
void updateLastRoute(String routeName) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('lastRoute', routeName);
}

return GoRouter(
    initialLocation: "/",
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(authRepository.authStateChanges()),
    redirect: (context, state) async {
        final path = state.uri.path;
        final uid = authRepository.currentUser?.uid;
        final isLoggedIn = authRepository.currentUser != null;
        final user = await ref.watch(userInfoProvider.future);
        final business = await ref.watch(businessProvider.future);
        if (!isLoggedIn && path == "/") {
            return '/signIn';
        }
        if (isLoggedIn && business == null && path == "/") {
            return '/setup/personal';
        }
        if (business != null &&
            (path == "/setup/personal" || path == "/setup/business")) {
            return '/';
        }

        return null;
    },`


seems like it return at null . Make sure all conditions work properly.

I have checked all the conditions they are working properly the thing is at first it doesn't have any credential then after logged in the provider is refreshed and then appears a sign in page and goes for registration page and path is refreshed too so maybe that is the reason
please let me know if you need any more information

Did you find the reason for this?

remove async keyword from function on redirect

Your issue is actually due to the async nature of the redirect function. This is an issue with GoRouter's current implementation, with an open issue on the matter here.
As a workaround, you would need to move the redirect logic elsewhere. You could create a redirectProvider that would be triggered on authentication changes (or whatever else you need), and update its state with the destination the user should be redirected to. You would then use that state change in a ChangeNotifier to tell GoRouter to refresh (via its refreshListenable property) to read the new state of redirectProvider.
This way, the GoRouter's redirect function can remain sync (without the async keyword), and the black screen should go away.

You should remove async functions from the redirect function and create custom provider which will handle your for example auth state.
Example for login logic:
@riverpod
class Auth extends _$Auth {
  late final AuthRepositoryImpl _repository;

  @override
  AuthStatus build() {
    _repository = ref.read(authRepositoryProvider);
    return AuthStatus.uninitialized;
  }

  Future<User> signIn(SignInFormData formData) async {
    final result = await _repository.signIn(formData);
    state = AuthStatus.authenticated;
    return result;
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _repository.signOut();
    state = AuthStatus.unauthenticated;
  }
}

and in redirect REMOVE async keyword and listen to the provider changes
final authState = ref.watch(authProvider);
  final router = GoRouter(
    routes: _routes,
    initialLocation: RouterPaths.signIn,
    redirect: (context, state) {
      if (authState == AuthStatus.unauthenticated) {
        return RouterPaths.signIn;
      } else if (authState == AuthStatus.authenticated &&
          state.fullPath != RouterPaths.home) {
        return RouterPaths.home;
      }
      return null;
    },
  );
}

